# Do we really need a NetBeans tag for every version?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Do we really need a separate tag for [all the different versions of NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans-*)?

We currently have (with the number of questions):

- [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)× 8253
- [netbeans-7](/questions/tagged/netbeans-7)× 914
- [netbeans-7.3](/questions/tagged/netbeans-7.3)× 12
- [netbeans-7.2](/questions/tagged/netbeans-7.2)× 61
- [netbeans-7.1](/questions/tagged/netbeans-7.1)× 72
- [netbeans-7.0](/questions/tagged/netbeans-7.0)× 54
- [netbeans-6.9](/questions/tagged/netbeans-6.9)× 361
- [netbeans-6.8](/questions/tagged/netbeans-6.8)× 176
- [netbeans-6.7](/questions/tagged/netbeans-6.7)× 87
- [netbeans-6.5](/questions/tagged/netbeans-6.5)× 87
- [netbeans-6.1](/questions/tagged/netbeans-6.1)× 15

What should we do about these tags? Retag them all to [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) and clean up the crap questions while we are at it?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a netbeans guy but my colleagues had issues always after upgrading the version of netbeans. So when the software changes rapidly, some versioning in tag would be legitimate. Such as with [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) and [jsf-2](/questions/tagged/jsf-2).

But I think that those tags are too fragmented. Creating tag for each minor version makes it less probable that the persons browsing by tags will find such specific tag. So I suggest leaving tags for major versions ([netbeans-6](/questions/tagged/netbeans-6), [netbeans-7](/questions/tagged/netbeans-7)) for now. If after a few months it will be still too fragmented, the tag merge discussion can be raised again.